# How to config the autoformat no Lunar Vim

Tags: plugins, neovim

I'm newer on vim and your forks. To have a smoother transition I'm using Lunar Vim, but I need to change some option about the formatter, for example:

How I need to format:

```
<img src={ item.image } alt ={ item.descripton } />
```

But when I save, the Vim format like:

```
<img src={item.image} alt ={item.descripton} />
```

(Without spaces)

I need to change this, or remove the auto formatter.

Comment: I got disable the auto format changing the opting format_on_save to false, in the file config.lua -> linux path: /home/user/.config/lvim/

Comment: Could you please write your comment as an answer to mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this, you can do it with the easy way (answer of Jorge Dorino).

File: /home/user/.config/lvim/config.lua

```
lvim.format_on_save = true  -- Disable this line
```

Or you can keep this line and activate the prettier formatter https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html , and configure your own rules to html files formatting.
(You need to install prettier or prettierd before do this)

File: /home/user/.config/lvim/config.lua

```
  local formatters = require "lvim.lsp.null-ls.formatters"
  formatters.setup {
    { exe = "prettierd", filetypes = { "html" } }
  }
```